# .Net Core vs .NET Framework performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-core

I have a .NET Core class library (let's call it Core) and I want to use WPF GUI to use some of it's functionalities. But it seems .NET is very slow compared to .NET Core. For instance I have the following method that I would like to run:

```
private static void LoadData()
{
    Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();


    List<BookingRecord> records = new List<BookingRecord>();
    w.Start();
    string csv = File.ReadAllText("/BookingData/Booking_Data - Copy.csv");

    Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
    w.Restart();

    var lines = csv.Split('\n');

    foreach(var line in lines.Skip(1))
    {
        var data = line.Split(';');

        records.Add(new BookingRecord()
        {
            Origin = data[2],
            Destination = data[3],
            FlightDate = DateTime.Parse(data[4], new CultureInfo("De-de").DateTimeFormat),
            PassengersNumber = int.Parse(data[9])
        });
    }

    Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
    w.Stop();
}
```

For this I used two console apps, one under .NET Core, and one under .NET Framework. the time of constructing the list of `BookingData` under .NET Core is `0.4s`, while in .NET Framework case is around `10s`, which is problematic since I will be loading larger files of about 2 million lines and beyond (client requirement).

So is there any workaround this issue? The objective is to provide a GUI displaying results from  Core library.

***EDIT***

The snippet above is just to provide MCVE, otherwise, I'm reading the file using `StreamReader` with the help of `CsvHelper`, and the construction is done while reading.

***EDIT 2***

The loading and construction of data is built inside the Core library, in other words using .NET Core, the WPF or .NET Framework project in general, is just referencing the Core library and using its methods, it's just a display tool. Why does it have to produce the same result as when the code is moved to .NET project?

Comment: Yes, .Net is slower than .Net Core, but your way of reading the file isn't very performant to start with. You should try using a StreamReader and reading the file line by line instead of reading the complete file into memory as a first step.

Comment: @Compufreak, Thank you, Yes I'm using a StreamReader and reading and constructing line by line, The code included in the question just to provide MCVE.

Comment: The code above is not an MCVE. It's not complete, so it can't be verified. I created a test app that uses the "10,000" file from here: https://sample-videos.com/download-sample-csv.php with this code: https://pastebin.com/T3cipQZJ and when run on core/framework the times are very similar: 00:00:00.0285065 to 00:00:00.0621625 for CORE, 00:00:00.0350395 to 00:00:00.0421969 for FRAMEWORK. Raw results here: https://pastebin.com/q9eHm7Vj

Comment: @AndyJ, I think it is complete, I run nothing but the method provided, Also I couldn't produce the same results you got from your solution.
That being said, as I asked in EDIT 2. when I reference a dll from a .NET Core., in a .NET Framework, isn't it supposed to use .NET Core performance?

Comment: MCVE is defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve "Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem". The problem cannot be reproduced with the code you have provided. It doesn't have `BookingRecord`, nor does it have the data file you're loading up.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main reasons MS says you should use .Net Core is the performance gains.  A Google search seems to verify this.

However, regardless of which platform you use you will likely see better performance, and definitely better memory utilization, if you read the file one row at at a time using some sort of buffered reader.  Using ReadAllText is going to try to load all 2 millions lines into memory at once.  This isn't necessary if all you are doing is processing each line in the order they appear in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the list creation after you ave read the lines:

```
var lines = csv.Split('\n');
var records = new List<BookingRecord>(lines.Length);
```

This should create a huge difference. In your verison it will start with a underlying array of 8 items, when that is full create a new one of 16 items and copy the old ones over, when that is full create a underlying array of 32 items and copy the 16 over, etc.

Initializing it to the right size prevents this.  Maybe Core is able to do this in a smarter way already. It is supposed to be significantly faster although a factor of 25x seems to indicate there's something else at play here.

Even faster will be if you make the record a struct instead of a class as it can reserve the entire chunk of memory in one go instead of small bits per record.

Comment: The line `List<BookingRecord> records = new List<BookingRecord>();` isn't even being included in the measured time. `w.Start();` is after that line. Even if it was included, the time saved would be very very very small.

Comment: That line only creates the empty list with an underlying array of (i think) 8 items. That list is expanded and copied every time items are added and the array is full. The difference should be at least twice as fast.

Comment: Here is 1 million ints being added to a list, one way without an initial size, the other with an initial size: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0DayU4 There is a difference, and it's roughly 1.5x. But it's such a small amount of time that the natural variation between run times often drowns it out. To the point that some runs not supplying the size were faster than the runs which were supplying it. Supplying the size is faster, but it's negligible.

Comment: To be clear, I think it's good advice. What you're saying is right. But it's not the cause of "why does this take 10s?".

Comment: Haha nice one, ok conceaded. My hunch was that the 25x is more than just more efficient implementation of the same algorithms. Maybe Core is able to understand more about the code and take shortcuts like that itself. If only the Framework variant was affected more than the Core one this could point in that direction.

Comment: Next hunch would be a smarter garbage collector, creating millions of small objects and then having them promoted to Gen1 and Gen2 is costly too.

Comment: I've provided test code, data, and results in the comments on the question that show pretty much no difference between Core and Framework, so I have no idea what's going on for the OP. Since it's not reproducible I think it's something weird in OPs setup, rather than a "real" difference between Core and Framework. Interestingly if you don't supply a size it's initialized to 0. Then the first item added ups it to 4, then it doubles as needed after that: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs